# Using a Table as a Queue without sp_getapplock/sp_releaseapplock

Tags: sql-server, locking, concurrency, queue

I have a list of commands I need to execute, all of which are contained within a table I've named `myQueue`.  This table is a little unique in that some commands should be *grouped together* such that their execution is performed sequentially, rather than concurrently, as executing them concurrently causes unwanted data artifacts and errors.  Because of this, the queue cannot be classified in a typical **FIFO**/**LIFO** fashion as the dequeue order is determined at run-time.

To summarize:

1. A Table named `myQueue` will act as a command queue (where dequeue order is determined at run-time)
2. Commands are added to the table in a random way
3. Commands may fall into *groups*, and if so, must be executed by a single worker thread in an ordered, sequential manner
4. Any number of worker threads can be running when commands are being dequeued
5. Dequeuing is performed via an `UPDATE` rather than a `DELETE` as this table is used for historical performance reporting for said commands

My current approach is to iterate over this table using explicit mutex logic via [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)/[`sp_releaseapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-releaseapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) calls.  While this works as expected, the approach generates enough locking such that a high number of worker threads isn't feasible to iterate over the queue at any given time. After reading through Remus Rusanu's [excellent blog post on the topic](https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/), I decided to try utilizing table hints in hopes I could further optimize my approach.

I'll include the test code below, but to summarize my results, the downside to using table hints and eliminating calls to `sp_getapplock`/`sp_releaseapplock` results in up to three undesirable behaviors as follows:

1. Deadlocking
2. Multiple threads execute commands that are contained within a single *group*
3. Thread Assignments are missing within a *group* of commands

On a positive note though, when the code accommodates the deadlocking (e.g. retrying the offending operation as is currently included), the methods not using `sp_getapplock`/`sp_releaseapplock` and which don't exhibit undesirable behaviors 2 & 3 perform at least twice as fast, if not faster.

**What I'm hoping for is that someone will point out how I'm not structuring my dequeing statements correctly so I can still move forward with using table hints exclusively.**  If that doesn't work, so be it, but I wanted to see if it could be done just the same.

The tests can be setup with the following code.

The `myQueue` table creation and population with *commands* that are similar enough to my workload:

```
CREATE TABLE myQueue
(
    ID INT  IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Main    INT,
    Sub     INT,
    Detail  INT,
    Command VARCHAR(MAX),
    Thread  INT,
    StartDT DATETIME2,
    EndDT   DATETIME2
)
GO
INSERT INTO myQueue WITH (TABLOCKX) (Main, Sub, Detail, Command)
SELECT  ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 200),
        ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 1280),
        ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())),
        'WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:00.01'''
FROM sys.types t1 CROSS JOIN 
     sys.types t2 CROSS JOIN
     sys.types t3 CROSS JOIN
     (VALUES (1), (2)) t4(x)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_myQueue_Update]
ON [dbo].[myQueue] ([Main],[Sub])
INCLUDE (Thread, EndDT)
GO
```

Worker Threads all follow the same logic.  I recommend that if you run this locally, you just copy this code into separate query windows and run each query at the same time, making sure all Worker Threads adhere to the same locking method (there are 7 buried in the comments and surrounded by comment blocks):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @updOUT TABLE
(
    Main    INT,
    Sub     INT
)
-- Update @CurrentThread as a unique ID, I tend to
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @updOUT TABLE
(
    Main    INT,
    Sub     INT
)
-- @CurrentThread should be a unique ID, which I'm assigning as @@SPID
DECLARE @CurrentThread INT = @@SPID, 
        @main INT, @sub INT,
        @id INT, @command VARCHAR(MAX), 
        @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
WHILE   EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM myQueue WHERE EndDT IS NULL)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

        --/*
        -- Method 1: Top 1 WITH TIES within CTE, direct update against CTE, Contained with sp_getapplock/sp_releaseapplock
        -- works
        -- high volume of xp_userlock waits
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN

                EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = 'myQueue', @LockMode = 'Update'

                ;WITH dequeue AS
                (
                    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
                        Main, Sub, Thread
                    FROM    myQueue
                    WHERE   EndDT IS NULL
                        AND (Thread IS NULL OR Thread = @CurrentThread)
                    ORDER BY Main, Sub
                )
                UPDATE  dequeue
                SET Thread = @CurrentThread
                OUTPUT  DELETED.Main,
                        DELETED.Sub
                INTO @updOUT

                EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'myQueue'
            COMMIT
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'myQueue'
            ROLLBACK TRAN
        END CATCH
        --*/

        /*
        -- Method 2: Top 1 WITH TIES within CTE, direct update against CTE
        -- does not work
        -- some groupings contain multiple worker threads 
        -- missing thread assignments (e.g. NULL value in Thread Column)
        -- deadlocking experienced
        ;WITH dequeue AS
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
                Main, Sub, Thread
            FROM    myQueue WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
            WHERE   EndDT IS NULL
                AND (Thread IS NULL OR Thread = @CurrentThread)
            ORDER BY Main, Sub
        )
        UPDATE  dequeue
        SET Thread = @CurrentThread
        OUTPUT  DELETED.Main,
                DELETED.Sub
        INTO @updOUT
        */

        /*
        -- Method 3: Top 1 WITH TIES within CTE, join to myQueue table
        -- does not work
        -- some groupings contain multiple worker threads 
        -- missing thread assignments (e.g. NULL value in Thread Column)
        -- deadlocking experienced
        ;WITH dequeue AS
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
                Main, Sub, Thread
            FROM    myQueue WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
            WHERE   EndDT IS NULL
                AND (Thread IS NULL OR Thread = @CurrentThread)
            ORDER BY Main, Sub
        )
        UPDATE  myQ
        SET Thread = @CurrentThread
        OUTPUT  DELETED.Main,
                DELETED.Sub
        INTO @updOUT
        FROM    myQueue myQ WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
                    INNER JOIN dequeue
                        ON myQ.Main = dequeue.Main
                        AND myQ.Sub = dequeue.Sub 
        */

        /*
        -- Method 4: Top 1 within CTE, join to myQueue table
        -- does not work
        -- some groupings contain multiple worker threads
        ;WITH dequeue AS
        (
            SELECT TOP 1
                Main, Sub, Thread
            FROM    myQueue WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
            WHERE   EndDT IS NULL
                AND (Thread IS NULL OR Thread = @CurrentThread)
            ORDER BY Main, Sub
        )
        UPDATE  myQ
        SET Thread = @CurrentThread
        OUTPUT  DELETED.Main,
                DELETED.Sub
        INTO @updOUT
        FROM    myQueue myQ WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
                    INNER JOIN dequeue
                        ON myQ.Main = dequeue.Main
                        AND myQ.Sub = dequeue.Sub 
        */

        /*
        -- Method 5: Top 1 WITH TIES within CTE, join to myQueue table, PAGLOCK hint instead of ROWLOCK
        -- works*
        -- deadlocking experienced
        ;WITH dequeue AS
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
                Main, Sub, Thread
            FROM    myQueue WITH (PAGLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
            WHERE   EndDT IS NULL
                AND (Thread IS NULL OR Thread = @CurrentThread)
            ORDER BY Main, Sub
        )
        UPDATE  myQ
        SET Thread = @CurrentThread
        OUTPUT  DELETED.Main,
                DELETED.Sub
        INTO @updOUT
        FROM    myQueue myQ WITH (PAGLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
                    INNER JOIN dequeue
                        ON myQ.Main = dequeue.Main
                        AND myQ.Sub = dequeue.Sub 
        */

        /*
        -- Method 6: Top 1 WITH TIES within CTE, direct update against CTE, PAGLOCK hint instead of ROWLOCK
        -- works*
        -- deadlocking experienced
        ;WITH dequeue AS
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
                Main, Sub, Thread
            FROM    myQueue WITH (PAGLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
            WHERE   EndDT IS NULL
                AND (Thread IS NULL OR Thread = @CurrentThread)
            ORDER BY Main, Sub
        )
        UPDATE  dequeue
        SET Thread = @CurrentThread
        OUTPUT  DELETED.Main,
                DELETED.Sub
        INTO @updOUT

        */

        /*
        -- Method 7: Top 1 within CTE, join to myQueue table, PAGLOCK hint instead of ROWLOCK
        -- works*
        -- deadlocking experienced
        ;WITH dequeue AS
        (
            SELECT TOP 1
                Main, Sub, Thread
            FROM    myQueue WITH (PAGLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
            WHERE   EndDT IS NULL
                AND (Thread IS NULL OR Thread = @CurrentThread)
            ORDER BY Main, Sub
        )
        UPDATE  myQ
        SET Thread = @CurrentThread
        OUTPUT  DELETED.Main,
                DELETED.Sub
        INTO @updOUT
        FROM    myQueue myQ WITH (PAGLOCK, UPDLOCK, READPAST)
                    INNER JOIN dequeue
                        ON myQ.Main = dequeue.Main
                        AND myQ.Sub = dequeue.Sub 
        */

        SELECT  TOP 1 
              @main = Main
            , @sub = Sub
        FROM @updOUT

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT @ErrorMessage = 'Msg ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', Level ' + CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR(10)) 
            + ', State ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', Line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(10))
            + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ERROR_MESSAGE()

            RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 1, 1) WITH NOWAIT

            -- Set to Uselss values so cursor doesn't fire
            SELECT @main = -1, @sub = -1
        END CATCH

        DELETE FROM @updOUT

        DECLARE WorkQueueCur INSENSITIVE CURSOR
        FOR
            SELECT  ID, Command
            FROM    myQueue
            WHERE   Main = @main
                AND Sub = @sub
            ORDER BY Detail

        OPEN WorkQueueCur

        FETCH NEXT FROM WorkQueueCur
        INTO @id, @command

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            RETRY1:

            BEGIN TRY
                UPDATE  myQueue
                SET StartDT = GETDATE()
                WHERE ID = @id
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                SELECT @ErrorMessage = 'Retry1: Msg ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', Level ' + CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                + ', State ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', Line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(10))
                + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ERROR_MESSAGE()

                RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 1, 1) WITH NOWAIT

                GOTO RETRY1
            END CATCH

            EXEC(@command)

            RETRY2:

            BEGIN TRY
                UPDATE  myQueue
                Set EndDT = GETDATE()
                WHERE ID = @id
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                SELECT @ErrorMessage = 'Retry2: Msg ' + CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', Level ' + CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                + ', State ' + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR(10)) + ', Line ' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(10))
                + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ERROR_MESSAGE()

                RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 1, 1) WITH NOWAIT

                GOTO RETRY2
            END CATCH

            FETCH NEXT FROM WorkQueueCur
            INTO @id, @command
        END

        CLOSE WorkQueueCur
        DEALLOCATE WorkQueueCur


END
```

Confirmation of undesirable behaviors 2 and 3 (or lack thereof), above can be determined by running the following statement:

```
;WITH invalidMThread AS (
    SELECT  *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Main, Sub ORDER BY Thread) AS ThreadCount
    FROM    dbo.myQueue WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   StartDT IS NOT NULL
), invalidNThread AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    dbo.myQueue WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   Thread IS NULL
            AND StartDT IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  t1.*, 'Multiple Threads' AS Issue
FROM    dbo.myQueue t1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN invalidMThread i1
            ON i1.Main = t1.Main
            AND i1.Sub = t1.Sub
WHERE   i1.ThreadCount > 1

UNION

SELECT  t1.*, 'Unassigned Thread(s)' AS Issue
FROM    dbo.myQueue t1 WITH (NOLOCK) 
        INNER JOIN invalidNThread i2
            ON i2.Main = t1.Main
            AND i2.Sub = t1.Sub

ORDER BY t1.Main, t1.Sub
```

Again, I fully anticipate I missed some critical point Remus made in the blog post, so any help in pointing that out would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If some commands must be grouped together, you should consider having that group as your atomic item in a queue. This way, you will have to worry about locking issues a lot less, if at all. Also, if you need very high performance queue, perhaps database is not the right tool - consider using Kafka or RabbitMQ instead

Comment: If related commands are added randomly, how does the system know that any grouping is completely written to the table?

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider [SQL Server Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb522893(v=sql.105)), or do you have a limitation with the SQL Server Edition that you are using?

Comment: Service Broker is a possible (and likely better) approach to queuing in general, but it doesn’t address my question about if there is a way to structure the dequeing statements above differently such that usage of  `sp_getapplock`/`sp_releaseapplock` is no longer needed to avoid all of the issues I outlined.

Comment: Service Broker can work, but I've found significant issues with it when doing anything with high throughput queues.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues with your design.

- You are keeping history in the same table as your "active" queue items.  This makes finding items to dequeue take longer.
- Your dequeue process must necessarily scan all unprocessed items in order to lock the related items.  This must also necessarily block all other dequeue threads until thread 1 is sure that it has all related items locked.
- Your "related" items are added randomly.  As I asked in the comment, how does the dequeue thread know that all "related" items are ready for dequeue... or does that matter?  But what if thread 1 grabs items 1, 4, 5 for dequeue and while it's working, thread 2 grabs 2, 3, 6 and 7 and also starts.

So, suggestions:

Separate your Active Queue from your History.

Have a single process that allocates work for dequeue threads to handle.  This will group items together and make sure that a dequeue thread can quickly grab all related tasks.

I would suggest having a single thread that grabs unworked items, groups them and then spawns a new thread that does the work.  This could most readily be done using powershell.

Comment: LOL, there are more than a _few issues_ wrong with the design, admittedly. However, your first concern is resolved with a **filtered** covering index (i.e. `WHERE EndDT IS NULL` ) which effectively separates history out. The issue with using a single thread to manage the queue, let's call it the manager thread (MT) approach, is when a worker thread completes commands as fast, if not faster than the MT is able to assign out the work, which effectively limits this to one worker thread in that situation. The objective is to throw more and more worker threads at the dataset as much as possible...

Comment: ... Obviously there's a theoretical limit to how _concurrent_ any process can become, but it needs to be more than 1. PowerShell also presents concerns as it's 1) external to SQL Server and can therefore be terminated without SQL knowing about it and 2) doesn't add any concurrency optimizations not already available within TSQL. I appreciate the feedback though!